# How to dynamically change upload_tmp_dir via an apache module version of PHP dynamically, i.e. before the uploading file is written to disk

Tags: php, uploading

I want to rotate the location where temporary files are written however it is my understanding that the PHP script wont execute until after the full post is already completed.  By that time the file is already written to the default temp location from the configuration file which is loaded in at the time apache is spawned and the php module is loaded.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mention, it isn't possible to change it dynamically since the upload is completed before the page executes -- i.e. no fancy `ini_set` calls can be made.

A possible workaround:

You could set the temporary upload location in your `php.ini` file to point to a symlink (`/tmp/myuploads`) that in turn points to one of your chosen upload locations (`/mnt/uploadstore_1/`).

You can then have the PHP file that handles the upload change the symlink location to a new location each time it runs ( basically the equivalent of a '`rm /tmp/myuploads && ln -s /mnt/uploadstore_2/ /tmp/myuploads`').

This should make sure that the upload that comes next ends up in your next-in-line chosen location.

Comment: The only problem is if there are a bunch of uploads occuring at once this wont work becuase it will break previously uploaded files.  It only works if you have a stopping point where you can safely repoint the symlink however if there was a safe point there would be no need for the symlink as its needed to reduce disk load.  The only real solution might be external to PHP.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem with the symlink technique..

A simple perl script could do the job of handling the upload though. There is a sample upload handler here:
http://www.sitepoint.com/article/uploading-files-cgi-perl/2/

Good luck!

Comment: It looks like CGI.pm also depends on a temp dir of its own before handing off the $CGI->upload file handle to the calling script. Search for "temporary directory" in CGI.pm. So you'd be in the same boat with perl, at least if you used CGI.pm. I suppose you could roll your own cgi handler from scratch and decide what to do with the file then.

Comment: i think there might be a workaround involving apache php_admin_value and dynamic rewrite maps